# LINQ query returning null when running Unit Test only

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, unit-testing, datacontext

I have a public method that I use to log a user into my web application. I am attempting to test this method via a 'Unit test' .cs file in a 'Unit test Project' in VS2013.

This is my test method -

```
[TestClass]
public class UserTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_LogInUser()
    {
          Assert.IsTrue(UserActions.LogInUser("testusername", "testpassword!"));
    }
}
```

As you can see I am passing in two parameters to my method. In the 'LogInUser' method I then take the "testusername" parameter and use it in a LINQ query to see if this users exists in my local database. I am using **Entity Framework** and a **custom DataContext** to communicate with the database as shown  -

```
 var query = _db.Customer.FirstOrDefault(
            c => c.Username == username);
```

**The issue is that my query is returned null**, but if I debug the same method with the application running **a result is returned by the query**. Is there anything I can do to make my unit tests recognise this DataContext as I suspect this is what is leading to my query returning null?

Comment: Normally, the methods that you test should be isolated from any external dependencies. But it is always the programmers choice.

Comment: Thank you for your response, most of the responses I have seen on the net do suggest they should be independent. But logically I should be able to test the actual logic that will be run by the  application, otherwise I can't see why unit testing is worth it.

Comment: Yes, the purpose of unit testing is to make sure that the function is working as 'expected'. Unit test should test only that 'UNIT' of code. If you start testing the 'flow' then your test will flow through several methods that you are invoking within the method that you are testing. You need to see IoC, mocking, etc., to write pure and effective unit tests. I am not sure, if it makes sense, may be some experts out there in SO can comment on it.

Comment: Informative answer thanks. I have taken a look at mocking but I didn't want to commit time to it unless it was definitely the right direction to go.